# Increment Row Number on Group each time it 'reappears' in R

Tags: r

Is it possible in R, to create a column that increases in increments of 1 each time a group level of another column 'reappears', i.e.

View(x)

```html
vents    Group     Number of times present
    1           1               1
    2           1               1
    3           1               1
    4           2               1
    5           1               2
    6           1               2
    7           2               2
    8           2               2 
    9           3               1
    10          2               3
    11          3               2
    12          3               2
    13          2               4
    14          1               3
    15          1               3
```

(wherby my desired result would be the 'Number of times present column'

Assuming the above example is my dataframe, I have tried:

`x <- within(x, {Number of times present<- cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(Group))))})`

However this just increases by one every time the group level changes (regardless of what group it is and the past history of the number of times it previously 'reappeared'

Any help will be greatly appreciated (my actual dataframe is very large, but im guessing a for loop may be the way forward?

Thankyou

Comment: Can you post the result of `dput(x)` instead of an image? Also show expected output.

Comment: you are looking for `rleid`

Comment: this might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964402/clustering-rows-by-group-based-on-column-value

Comment: Unfortunately the stack flow question of clustering rows, whilst similar, is slightly different in the fact that by 'group' column is not just 0's and 1's, but can go up to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by `rle` function and 1 `for` loop：

```
x <- data.frame(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1))

rle(x$Group)
# Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:9] 3 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2
#  values : num [1:9] 1 2 1 2 3 2 3 2 1

y1 <- rle(x$Group)$values
y2 <- rle(x$Group)$lengths
z <- c()
for(i in unique(y1)){
    z[y1 == i] <- 1 : sum(y1 == i)
}

rep(z, y2)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 3 2 2 4 3 3
```

Comment: Thankyou. This was exactly what I wanted! If you do not mind could explain the code in the loop and how it worked?